Why unstable_cache in NextJs is not caching?
I'm really struggling to understand why my code is not caching via unstable_cache function:
import { unstable_cache } from "next/cache";

const getRandomNumber = unstable_cache(
    async () => {
        const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999) + 1000;

        return randomNumber;
    },
    [`random_number`],
    {
        tags: [`random_number`],
        revalidate: 3600
    }
)

export default async function ComponentFunction() {
    const number = await getRandomNumber();

    return <div>
        {number}
    </div>
}

Every time I refresh the page, I get a different random number!
I also tried to following things:

Move the definition of getRandomNumber inside the component function
Move the definition of getRandomNumber in an external file and import the exported function

Nothing works!
Can someone please explain why?
Thanks!

can you build and run your app in the production env and see if the result samke

Somehow, now it's working... I didn't change anything. Just re-run the application! I'll switch soon to the new directive 'use cache'. :)

maybe that is why it is called "unstable"
